# JPQL Query to select entity from one-to-one relationship where it's relative has a field matching a certain condition

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, plsql, jpql

I have three entities: `EntityA` maps to `table_a`, `EntityB` maps to `table_b`, and `Catalog` maps to `catalog`. In the database, there's a many-to-many table between `table_b` and `catalog`, `b_catalog_xref`. `EntityB` has a field: `Long aId`, and a field: `List<Catalog> catalogs`. The Catalog entity has a field: `String name`. Given a list of IDs for EntityB, and a string representing a catalog name, I need to retrieve all occurrences of EntityA whose ID matches that of an EntityB's `aId`, and where the given catalog name matches that of one of EntityB's catalogs.

I've successfully grabbed the correct data via regular SQL, but I'm struggling to recreate the query in JPQL. Here's the SQL query:

**SQL:**

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
    table_a a
WHERE
    a.table_a_id in (
    SELECT
        b.table_a_id
    FROM
        table_b b
        INNER JOIN b_catalog_xref bcx ON bcx.table_b_id = b.table_b_id
        INNER JOIN catalog c ON c.catalog_id = bcx.catalog_id
    WHERE
        c.catalog_name = 'Example Catalog Name'
);
```

**Java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_a")
public class EntityA {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "table_a_id")
    private Long aId;

    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_b")
public class EntityA {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "table_b_id")
    private Long bId;

    @Column(name = "table_a_id")
    private Long aId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH})
    @JoinTable(name = "b_catalog_xref",
               joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "table_b_id")},
               inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "catalog_id")})
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OrderBy("name ASC")
    List<Catalog> catalogs

    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "catalog")
public class Catalog {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "catalog_id")
    private Long catalogId;

    @Column(name = "catalog_name")
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think I've figured it out. Here's what I have so far:
```SELECT
  a
    FROM
     EntityA AS a
    WHERE
     a.aId IN (
      SELECT
       b.aId
      FROM
       EntityB AS b
      LEFT JOIN
       b.catalogs AS bCatalog
  WITH
   bCatalog.name = :catalogName
     )```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use something like

```
TypedQuery<TableA> q = entityManager.createQuery
            ("Select a from TableA a where a.aId in(Select b.aId from TableB b " +
                    "join b.catalogs c where c.name=:name)", TableA.class);
q.setParameter("name", "some2");
```

I advise you to consider creating a relationship between tables A and B instead of copying the key of table A to table B

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_b")
public class EntityB {
...
//    @Column(name = "table_a_id")
//    private Long aId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "table_a_id")
    private TableA tableA;
...
}
```

Then JPQL will look like:

```
TypedQuery<TableA> q = entityManager.createQuery
                ("Select distinct b.tableA from TableB b join b.catalogs c " +
                        "where c.name=:name", TableA.class);
q.setParameter("name", "some2");
```

Pay attention to the keyword distinct, it removes all duplicates in the result list.

And do not use `FetchType.EAGER` unless absolutely necessary, use `FetchType.LAZY`.

Comment: I totally agree that there should be an explicit relationship between the two entities, but this is a core entity in a massive codebase, and I can only imagine how much will break if I changed that. Some time, when I have some spare time, I'll probably refactor it.